# Are these two pronunciations of 그럼 valid?

Tags: pronunciation

On forvo, there's two pronunciations of [그럼](https://forvo.com/word/ko/%EA%B7%B8%EB%9F%BC/#ko). The two sound different to me. The one by fairybel sounds like the second syllable has more of an "ㅏ" sound than a "ㅓ" sound, as if it were "그람", whereas the one by ativ sounds like what I expected: a "ㅓ" sound in the second syllable. (Though I'm not proficient enough to distinguish "ㅓ" from "ㅗ")

What's going on? Do the two pronunciations sound the same to Korean speakers? Do they sound like the same word but with regional accents? Or is one of them incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a native Korean. I've replayed the recordings on forvo several times, but those two pronunciations sound same to me. They are not saying it with regional accents, either.

Correct pronunciation is [그럼].